# Responsive menu missing

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm new here and I've started with coding few months ago. Now I'm creating one site and I have a problem with responsive menu.

I used Arcana html5 up template and problem is that responsive menu is displayed on homepage but it's not working on any others  even if the code (HTML) is the same.

Where is the problem? Can you help me please?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that pathing to your javascript assets near the footer are using relative pathing, if you try open the files that are being called such as `assets/js/main.js` you will notice that they are not working on all pages not being the home page.

Try calling the assets from the root using `/` , e.g..

```
/assets/js/main.js
```

in place of

```
assets/js/main.js
```

The CSS in the head is working because it is using absolute pathing, e.g..

```
http://www.mvlgiraltovce.php5.sk/assets/css/main.css
```